# React authentication isn't updating properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication

when i have my functions in UserAuthContext.js my App isn't working properly. I try to login but the user is not directet to /browse as it should. But if i put the same code in app.js i can create and login with an account. I don't know what the reason is
here is the code
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-euler-eicfr?file=/src/App.js
-not working version (above code belongs to this): https://not-working.netlify.app/
-working version where i have the code in app.js
https://netflix-clone-kasamtde.netlify.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `useAuthContext` in a component that is not a child of `UserAuthContextProvider`. It will always return `undefined`

Easiest fix for this is to move `UserAuthContextProvider` into `index.js`:

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import UserAuthContextProvider from "./components/Contexts/UserAuthContext.js";


render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <UserAuthContextProvider><App /></UserAuthContextProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Gosh i thought about that yesterday but i didn't try it out. Now that u mention it, it is clearer now. thank you very much